# How do I correctly create my goals for Google Analytics event tags?

Tags: events, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have setup some goals in the last week and results still aren't filtering through - I have a feeling its due to my poor knowledge of RegEx and the dynamic nature of the events I want to be tracking.

We track clicks on car makes, so I have created a goal with, action that matches:

```
UsedCars.Model.Homepage.
```

An example of an event that we have:

```
trackable_UsedCars.Model.Homepage.Subaru.Impreza STI
```

I want to be able to have a goal that collates **ALL** of these actions as a goal set, however feel that the full-stops (periods for US readers) are causing some mayhem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following RegEx in Google Analytics...

`UsedCars\.Model\.Homepage\.`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have put this into our analytics and will let you know the outcome.